# Sort li and event handlers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

So, I am having an issue with sorting a list where I lose any event handlers attached to the list items. I know how to sort the list just fine using w/e filter I desire, just I can't figure out how to retain the event handlers attached to each list element. So, the code...

HTML

```
<ul id="classes">
    <li class="class_2" date-created="Sat Jan 04 2014 20:46:55 GMT-0500 (EST)">Calc 152<di class="class_list_arrow"></di></li>
    <li class="class_3" date-created="Mon Jan 06 2014 21:26:59 GMT-0500 (EST)">Phys 133<di class="class_list_arrow"></di></li>
</ul>
```

The Sorting JS

```
function ascending (){
    var rows = $('#classes li').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

      var A = new Date($(a).attr('date-created')).getTime();
      var B = new Date($(b).attr('date-created')).getTime();

      //var events = $._data($(a).get(0), "events");
      //alert(JSON.stringify(events));

      if(A < B) {
        return -1;
      }

      if(A > B) {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;     
   });

    $('#classes').html('');
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
             $('#classes').append(row);
    });
}
```

So...here is where I am stuck. I can get the attr. date-created just fine and sort how I need to, but on each li element I have a 'tap' event handler and a 'swiperight swipeleft' handler and these are lost after the sort and append back to the dom.

I am pretty sure I need to use that $._data method that I have stored in var events...but not sure how to go about it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: remove this line and see: `$('#classes').html('');` Appending an already existing element just move it, keeping attached handlers

Comment: @A. Wolff: I think, that will duplicate the list items.

Comment: @AshishKumar no it will not since they are not cloned.

Comment: @A. Wolff: Wow, the answer is always easier than I thought ahah. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this html

```
<ul id="classes">
  <li class="l_3" data-doc="Mon Jan 06 2014 22:26:59 GMT-0500 (EST)">a</li>
  <li class="l_1" data-doc="Sat Jan 04 2014 20:46:55 GMT-0500 (EST)">b</li>
  <li class="l_2" data-doc="Mon Jan 06 2014 21:00:09 GMT-0500 (EST)">c</li>         
</ul>
<button onclick="SortAscending()">sort</button>
```

and the `function SortAscending()` like this:

```
function SortAscending ()
{    
    var rows = $('#classes li').get();
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
          var A = new Date($(a).attr('data-doc')).getTime();
          var B = new Date($(b).attr('data-doc')).getTime();
          if(A < B) { return -1; }
          if(A > B) { return 1; }
          return 0;     
    });

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
             $('#classes').append(row);
    });    
}
```

Every event handler stays attached.

#### Reason from the jQuery source

As  `A. Wolff` pointed out the part `$('#classes').html('')` was the culprit. In the jQuery-Source of the `html()` function there is something like this:

```
 if ( typeof value === "string" .... )
 {
    ...
    for (; i < l; i++ )
    {
       // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
       elem = this[i] || {};
       if ( elem.nodeType === 1 )
       {
          jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
          elem.innerHTML = value;
       }
    }
 }
```

So calling `$('#classes').html('')` gets evaluated as passing a string and clears all attached handlers.

I tested it with this code if the handlers are still attached.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".l_1").on("click", function(){ alert("item 1")});
    $(".l_2").on("click", function(){ alert("item 2")});
    $(".l_3").on("click", function(){ alert("item 3")});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation of what was happening behind the scenes there!